# Configuring Jetty with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jetty, pom.xml

I am having trouble configuring Jetty to run with Spring MVC, which is getting a bit frustrating.

Overall the configuration works, since if I run it with tomcat works fine. As soon as I try to add jetty and configure the build, it blows up and gives me the following error

```
22:21:58.663 [main] ERROR o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
```

The cause of this error seems to be related to

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [persistence.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

[WARNING] unavailable
```

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.helloworld.config.WebConfig]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundExcepti
on: class path resource [persistence.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

But how is this a problem? It works file when I use Tomcat, and there is no issues with classpaths, and locating my files.

Here is my pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.helloworld</groupId>
<artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>HelloWorld</name>

<properties>
    <spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <!--<spring.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>-->
    <jetty.version>9.2.6.v20141205</jetty.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.12</slf4j.version>
    <logback.version>1.1.2</logback.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>webjars</id>
        <url>http://webjars.github.com/m2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.36</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.191</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Thymeleaf Template Engine -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Thymeleaf Layout Dialect  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- WebJars -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <finalName>HelloWorld</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.8.v20160314</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/hellworld/home</contextPath>
                </webApp>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

I think the issue is within pom and how it's set up?

Comment: Do you have a file named `persistence.properties`

Comment: Yes of course, it's under webapp/meta-inf/recourses/persistence.properties

Comment: try to put it under src/main/resources

Comment: and don't spell "resources" wrong ("recourses" vs. "resources").

Comment: That was a typo, sorry. But my point is that if I dont use jetty it works. My resources, and webjars being found when I run the project in tomcat without jetty configuration in pom.xml. Why is this a problem for jetty? Does it change the classpath, or it internally configures something that ower-rights something?

Comment: Didnt work, still says it cant find the file, and from the debug log it says that src/main/resources don't exist. Why would this happen?